# Tips for Magazine Cover?

Tags: color, inkscape, white-space

School artistic magazine, done in Inkscape. [image]

Not sure about the readability of the entirety, nor about the colors for the text. Any tips would be great.

Also, someone told me that all that whitespace down there is a good thing... seems almost too empty though.

Comment: the "/" only makes sense when it's non-annually. 3/2018 as "third edition of 2018".

Comment: Personally, I would say you have made the creative statement and splash of colour with the background art - I would have a clean, clear sans serif (e.g. Frutiger med to bold) for the qualifying text in one dark colour sampled from the background - the juxtaposition of the two will also create a tension / contrast (which is good).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why anyone would bother answering if you've already chosen what you see as the "correct" answer :) You might do better to wait a bit before hitting that "correct" button so quickly. Anyway....

I mostly agree with Lucian, however....

- "Introducing" is pretty poor on readability. The typeface appears to be a poor readability typeface to begin with then laying it on top the artwork further deceases it's readability. If it were me, I'd choose a more readable script typeface if you want script.

Everything else is readable though. I too would remove the forward slash before "2018". It's superfluous. I so however also feel "THE" is *far* too close to the left edge. Also not sure why "THE" is all uppercase when "introducing" isn't.

- As for the crest and url. I'd stack these and center them at the bottom. The lower left corner of any design is the *least visible* space. You really should try to avoid placing content in lower left corners. Sometimes it's okay if the content is not really important, but I'd imagine the crest and URL a bit more than unimportant.

If you were to place these on the right side, they'd throw the rest of the deign off balance. If you were to leave then configured horizontally and center them, again, they'd throw off the balance of the rest of the piece. By stacking them and centering, crest above the URL, you maintain balance overall and get them out of that lower left corner. Becuase of this alteration I might consider reducing the size of the primary art a bit and moving "2018" slightly closer to the border on multicolored art.

Comment: There is no reason to wait with accepting an answer. You may rethink your decision any time. Better accept early, then you don't forget about it.

Comment: @userunknown It's not about the questioner waiting.... it's about OTHER users actually answering. If a question is marked correct it *will* deter some users from providing more, and different, answers. This is *especially* true with more subjective questions. These types of questions aren't like StackOverflow coding questions where once something is answered, it's correct and done.

Comment: An accepted answer on SO might be incorrect, it might be correct but there might be more elegant, secure, didactic or performant answers, there might be answers, which fit today in the presence of new language features or updates. A single, fitting answer is automatically the best answer. If new answers arrive, they might be better. You don't know, what other users expect.

Comment: Okay.. clearly you must have way more experience than I do here. Not going to argue it. I disagree. Subjective questions actually benefit from slower answer selection in my, apparently meager, experience. (5 minutes was rather quick to choose an answer to a critique question)

Answer (score 4):

The other two answers are very good.

I'd like to add that the "IMP" looks slightly shifted to the left compares to the "ART". This is mainly due to the whiteapace in the P of IMP and the A of ART.
You could try to move the IMP slightly to the right (will result in the logo being geomentrically imperfect) or adjusting the letters A and P. This font has no Serif but maybe adding a foot to the P might help.

Answer (score 2):

Whitespace is good, i would actually shrink down the main illustration (everything above 2018) while keeping it centered, to add some more whitespace at the top and on the sides. I would remove the "/" before 2018 and move the URL up so it gets centered vertically with the round symbol on the left.

Answer (score 1):

The **IMP/ART/MAG** looks very industrial, while the *Introducing, THE, /2018* form an informal contrast. That's fine.

I could read the *Introducing* without problems, while English isn't my mother tongue. But both, *Introducing* and *THE* are struggling for the introducing role on the language level. For my taste, one is too much. I would sacrifice the *THE*. From the balance, some other graphical element at that place might be ok and needed, to get a good balance and prevent a too static look.

I agree on the inconsistency of uppercase in THE, and the slash  before the year. The logo in the lower left looks ok for me.